# jquery_ujs and/or turbolinks stops js events from happening on form submit button

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have `jQuery`, `jQuery-ujs`, and `turbolinks` in my app (default dependencies in rails 5 apps).

When the submit button is clicked, I want to `fadeIn` a loading spinner (animated spinner from font-awesome).

Assume that the loading spinner is hidden on the page.  Here is the code for the submit button and the spinner:

```
<div class="actions">
  <%= form.submit id: 'submit-btn' %>
</div>

<div id='load-icon'>
  <i class="fa fa-refresh fa-spin fa-3x fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  <span class="sr-only">Refreshing...</span>
</div>
```

And then I have the following, which is supposed to put an event listener on that submit button, which fades in the spinner once the button is clicked:

```
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function () {
  $('#submit-btn').on('click', function(){
    $('#load-icon').fadeIn();
  });
});
```

The search takes a while to load the information, but the spinner does not appear.  I know this has to either do with turbolinks, jQuery-ujs, or both which are stopping the javascript from executing when the button is clicked.

Ultimately my question is: How can I get javascript to run when a submit form button is clicked?

Comment: Have showing any error in the console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the latest [`turbolinks`](https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks#observing-navigation-events) documentation.  Use `document.addEventListener("turbolinks:load", function() {` instead of `$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function () {` .  So, the code looks like this:

```
document.addEventListener("turbolinks:load", function() {
  $('#submit-btn').on('click', function(){
    $('#load-icon').fadeIn();
  });
});
```

It was tested and it is working properly for me.